# How to set up GIT on VM with shared Drive?

Tags: windows, git, virtual-machine

I have been having trouble setting up GIT I keep getting the error:

> fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at ...

After hours of googling and trouble shooting, I finally found the reason.
I am working on a VM that uses a mapped share folder from my main Machine as 'D:'.
I do this for various reason but mostly so I can test easily from different OS / languages.

I get this error on the VM.

When I installed GIT on the main machine it worked without issue.

Is there a way to set this up? Or can I only run GIT from the main machine?

The suggestion from GIT of adding a 'safe directory' had no effect.

Comment: _"The suggestion from GIT of adding a 'safe directory' had no effect."_ - What was this "safe directory" you speak-of? (btw, `git` is not called "GIT", it's never capitalized)

Comment: Generally speaking, git [_working-trees_](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefworkingtreeaworkingtree) are not meant to be concurrently accessed by multiple machines (unless you're absolutely certain all systems share the same file-locking semantics and have the same effective `git config` settings - otherwise you'll corrupt your files and mess-up things like LFS blobs and line-endings). git's core functionality depends on local OS cached data (`fscache`, etc) which won't work when files are modified without all hosts knowing about it.

Comment: ...as for non-concurrent access - that's certainly less dangerous (as it doesn't depend on network-aware file locking). I imagine _at worst_ you'll encounter less-serious issues caused by differences in machine-scoped `git config` settings - and stuff like commit-signing-keys being unavailable.

Comment: Nevermind, adding a Safe directory does work... It just needs to be in the right place.
I don't know what the git is doing, but the .gitconfig file is in 2 places... One is on the 'Users' DFS, the other is local (C:/Users where it should be) for some reason my safe directory commands were stored on the DFS, when I copied them manually to to C:/Users it now works... WTH

Comment: New question, how do I tell it stop using the DFS.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "DFS"? Are you referring to [Windows' DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft)) _specifically_ - or something else?

Comment: The company network. Every user has a 'personal drive' mapped to Z:/.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your company have an on-prem repo server or anything like that? If they're using MS DFS to implement their SMB shares then it's plausible they could set you up with a proper git environment rather than bodge-jobs with network-shares...

Comment: That is each user has has a Z:/ and see it like a normal drive, but it is mapped by the 'Dynamic File System' (DFS), yes windows. If I go onto the Server I can see that \\DFS\Users\(LOGIN) is actually where the files go...

Comment: The network shares aren't for code :) we all have it local, but yes we have a Repo Server (GitLAB)

Comment: Thanks for help! If I unmap Z: it works, as that is where the (git) config was incorrect.